# Exclude css files by default when checking in

Tags: css, visual-studio, tfs, less

I am using Less in Visual Studio to generate css files. When I check in I only want to check in the less files and exclude the generated css files. Is it possible to exclude css files by default when checking in?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Local Workspaces?

Comment: Also, what version of TFS 2010/12/Service?

Comment: Hi, I am using TFS 2012 and not local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Local Workspaces**, you should be able to use a [`.tfignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore) file to ignore the css files like so:

```
######################################
# Ignore .css files in this folder and all its sub-folders
*.css
```

If you are using **Server Workspaces**, I think you will just have to avoid adding them when you use the Add Files to Source Control dialog. You can sort by the file type and select all the css files and choose "Exclude"